# $f(x+1) = e^D f(x)$ why and when does it hold

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

From Spivak's Calculus, third edition, at page 564 problem 17:

Taylor's theorem implies, disregarding questions of convergence, that
$f(x+1) = e^D f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}$

And indeed for some analytic functions I've tried it seems to be true. But does it hold for all analytic functions, and why? I can't see how it follows from Taylor's theorem.

Thanks.

Comment: $f(x+h)$ with $h=1$ the $h^n$ are omitted since they are $1$.

Comment: Is $e^D$ like the [product integral](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral)?

Comment: @TymaGaidash https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator?wprov=sfla1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have$$f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)h+\frac{f''(x)}{2!}h^2+\frac{f^{(3)}(x)}{3!}h^3+\cdots,$$and therefore, taking $h=1$,$$f(x+1)=f(x)+f'(x)+\frac{f''(x)}{2!}+\frac{f^{(3)}(x)}{3!}+\cdots.$$If $D$ is the differentiation operator, this becomes$$f(x+1)-f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{D^n(f)(x)}{n!}.$$So, $f(x+1)-f(x)$ is equal to $\bigl((e^D-1)(f)\bigr)(x)$,